# pandas hierarchical index slicing based on year index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, hierarchical

I have a dataset, `data1`. I am trying to use indexing slicing based on `input`

where `data1 =`

```
                  stats
gender  year    
        
women   2003    cellphone use
        2007    height
        2007    cigarette use
        2008    weight
        2009    cellphone use
        2015    cigarette use
        2018    weight
        2020    height
```

Here is my attempt at index slicing:

```
 isvalid_yr = False
 while not isvalid_yr:
     year_input = int(input("Input the year you want to compare data from: "))
     if year_input in data1.index.get_level_values('year') 
         idx = pd.IndexSlice
         isvalid_yr = True
         new_data1 = data1.loc(axis = 0)[idx[year_input:year_input], idx[:]]
     else:
          isvalid_yr = False
     try:
         if isvalid_yr ==True:
             pass
         else:
             raise ValueError("Year not in data!")
         except ValueError as err:
             print("Year not in data!")
```

It gives me this output which I do not want.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [stats]
Index: []
```

my final desired output that I want to achieve would look like this

`Input the year you want to compare data from: 2007`

result of `new_data1 =`

```
                  stats
gender  year    

women   
        2007    height
        2007    cigarette use
```

Comment: Error here?  `if prompt_yr in data1.index.get_level_values('year')`  Shouldn't prompt_yr be year_input?

Comment: good catch thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas-dataframe-xs) to grab a cross-section of the DataFrame:

```
res = df.xs(2007, axis=0, level='year', drop_level=False)
```

`res`:

```
                     stats
gender year               
women  2007         height
       2007  cigarette use
```

With user input:

```
while True:
    try:
        year_input = int(
            input("Input the year you want to compare data from: ")
        )
        res = df.xs(year_input, axis=0, level='year', drop_level=False)
        break
    except KeyError:
        print("Year not in data!")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid year")
```

---

`df` used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'gender': ['women', 'women', 'women', 'women', 'women', 'women', 'women',
               'women'],
    'year': [2003, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2015, 2018, 2020],
    'stats': ['cellphone use', 'height', 'cigarette use', 'weight',
              'cellphone use', 'cigarette use', 'weight', 'height']
}).set_index(['gender', 'year'])
```

`df`:

```
                     stats
gender year               
women  2003  cellphone use
       2007         height
       2007  cigarette use
       2008         weight
       2009  cellphone use
       2015  cigarette use
       2018         weight
       2020         height
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way around casting my input as an int? I would preferably like to leave it as year_input = input("Input the year you want to compare data from: ")

Comment: Not if your year values are type `int`.

Comment: I want to somehow prevent the program from terminating if a user entered a string or something other than an int for the input.  for example, if user entered "asdas" I would want it to simply reprompt with message "Invalid year, enter again".  rather than terminating the program.

Comment: Add an `except` to catch value errors. See the edit.